# Zlib is unable to extract a compress String in java, compression is done in python

Tags: python, java, zlib, jzlib

Im trying to decompress a string in java, the string is compress in python with base64 encoding.

I tried a day to resolve the issue, The file can decode easily online and also in python.
Find similar post that people have trouble compressing and decompressing in java and python.

[zip.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/t/w8BU2Blznu6P49qJ)

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class CompressionUtils {
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

public static byte[] decompress(final byte[] data) {
    final Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream =
            new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[data.length];
    try {
        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            final int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (DataFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("ZlibCompression decompress exception: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    inflater.end();
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    decompress(Base64.getDecoder().decode(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("zip.txt"))));
}
}
```

Error:

```
 java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check
    at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytesBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:378)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:464)
```

**Tried also this after @Mark Adler suggestion.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("zip.txt")));
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded);
    GZIPInputStream gzStream = new GZIPInputStream(in);
    decompress(gzStream.readAllBytes());
    gzStream.close();
}

java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check
at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytesBytes(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:378)
at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:464)
at efrisapi/com.efrisapi.util.CompressionUtils.decompress(CompressionUtils.java:51)
at efrisapi/com.efrisapi.util.CompressionUtils.main(CompressionUtils.java:67)
```

Comment: The `zip.txt` file seems to contain base64 data as you mention. If you decode it and save it as a ZIP file, can you open it with your operating system ZIP file manager?

Comment: The txt in the file is string. you can see the string when upload to link https://codebeautify.org/zlib-decompress-online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a gzip stream, not a zlib stream. Use `GZIPInputStream`.

Comment: How do you know it’s a Gzip?

Comment: I looked at it.

Comment: I will try to check the header also to see if its Gzip, also kindly if you can explain how you manage to identify its a Gzip, it will help me also. also please check i have tried with GZIPInputStream but getting same error, i also tried with wrapon, but no avail. Thank you

Comment: I just wrote a code that I tried to read this file as a gzip stream and got this message "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format". So, I don't think this a gzip format

Comment: @MichaelGantman Yes, it is. Did you decode the Base64 encoding first?

Comment: @AqeelHaider I decoded the Base64 and ungzipped the result. The 18633 byte gzip stream decompresses to 114814 bytes of json data, which starts with _{"countryCode":[{"description":"SJ-Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands","name":"SJ-Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands","value":"SJ"}_...

Comment: @MarkAdler No, I didn't decode Base64 first. So, I guess you are right

Comment: No one just _looks_ at the data anymore. It's obvious it's Base64 if you just look at it.

Comment: Thank you i was looking in wrong direction, trying to decompress it using zlib.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in to wrong direction, the string was gzipped, below is the code to resolve it. Thank you **@Mark Adler** for identifying the issue.

```
public static void deCompressGZipFile(String gZippedFile, String newFile) throws IOException {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(gZippedFile)));
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded);
    GZIPInputStream gZIPInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(in);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = gZIPInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    // Keep it in finally
    fos.close();
    gZIPInputStream.close();
}
```